# How to keep Worksheet hyperlink to CellA1 in each worksheet when the worksheet name is changed

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am using *excel 2010* - I have 11 worksheets in a Testing plan template. The 1st Worksheet is an Overview with an Index that has *Hyperlinks to the Cell A1 in each worksheet.*

In each of the Worksheets in cell A1 is the formula "=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)& " Test Plan" this will update anytime the Test Plan worksheet name changes and will also add the text of " Test Plan".

On the Overview worksheet in the Index section captures whatever is in that *worksheet's cell A1* - When click the *Index* hyperlink it'll open to that Test Plan's worksheet.

However, when the Test Plan's worksheet name changes, of course the hyperlink is no longer functional and error is displayed.

What is the best way to retain the Index Hyperlink to a Test Plan worksheet's cell 1A no matter what the worksheet name is changed to and/or how often it's changed?

Note: Each default worksheet name is Module plus the worksheet# i.e.: Module (1), Module (2), Module (3) etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HYPERLINK` function along with a reference to a cell on the relevant worksheet.  The reference will track the correct spot regardless of the sheet name.  From there, you use `CELL` to get the address of that cell and feed it to `HYPERLINK`.

**Formula** in cell `A1` on sheet `Index`.  If you want better looking text for the cell, you can add a second parameter: `=HYPERLINK(..., "prettier text to display")`

```
=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",Data2!A1))
```

**Picture of sheet names and result**

[image: picture of result]

To do this multiple times, you just need to copy the formula and change the cell reference to the next sheet.  For 11 of these, that's not too bad.  If you had more, you could automate the formula creation with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a resolution - I was able to assign a "Defined Name" to the cell A1 for each worksheet and hyperlink from the index section on the Overview sheet to the cell A1 - and now whenever the Sheet name is changed, the hyperlink is still functional...So far that seems to be working, I have changed several of the worksheet names, and the hyperlink hasn't broken...